# LinkedIn thumbnail is wrong

Tags: html, linkedin-api, social-networking

Only on LinkedIn are the links' thumbnails I post incorrect. They work on Facebook, Twitter, Slack, what have you.

Using https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/, I am checking the thumbnails previews and they are incorrect. The image portion at the bottom recommends I use this code pattern.

```html
<meta name="image" property="og:image" content="[Image URL here]">
```

That is the syntax I am using in the `head` and it still insists on grabbing a random image on the page, specifically the author of our blog posts. The author's image appears in an `img` and nowhere else in the DOM. When I remove the author's image from the `img` `src`, the post inspector states that no image is found.

How can I get LinkedIn to show the correct thumbnails for my blog posts when the OG meta data is ineffective?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a page that is having this issue? Also, have you tried excluding the name attribute from the tag?

Comment: For confidentiality, I cannot share, but originally the name attribute was not included in the meta tag and was added per the post inspector's recommendations. So, either way it did not affect the outcome.

Comment: Hard to troubleshoot in that case. Best suggestions would be:
1. Make sure the image URL is truly correct and has no typos.
2. Make sure you can reach the image URL. Enter it into the browser (with the base URL if it's a relative path) to verify.
3. If you are also using the og:url meta tag, make sure that is properly formed as a URL (e.g., https://example.com, not just example.com). I've seen strange behavior when the og:url isn't a true URL.

Comment: Thank you @Ashavan. Some good advice and we attempted to apply all of these tips. I think we'll end up needing to contact LinkedIn support, though.